# Supremum and Infimum in an ordered Set

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to know if my proof for this theorem in Rudin's Analysis Text is correct:

Suppose S is an ordered set with the least-upper-bound property, $B$ $\subset S$ , $B$ is not empty and $B$ is bounded below Let $L$ be the set of all lower bounds of $B$. Then $$\alpha = \sup S$$ exists in $S$ $and$ $\alpha = \inf B$.In particular,$\inf B$ exists in S

My proof:

Since $B$ is bounded below, $L \not= \phi \implies \alpha = \sup L$ exists in S.

Pick $l \in L $ then l is a lower bound for $B$.Let $$\beta = \inf L$$

Clearly $$\alpha \ge l \space \forall l \in L\space\space\space\space\space and \space\space \beta \le b \space\space\forall b \in B $$ Now I make a claim : $$\alpha \le b \space\space\space\space\forall b \in B \space-------(1)$$. If it were false then $\alpha > b$ for some b. But then $b \ge l \space\space\space\space\forall l \in L $ which would contradict that $\alpha$ is the lub.

Now from $\textbf{(1)}$, $\space\alpha \in L\space\space$Also $\space\beta \le b \space\space\forall b \in B$ $\implies \beta \in L$. Since $\alpha$ is the lub of $L$, $\space\space\beta \le \alpha \space\space$.

From here we can show that $\alpha > \beta$ leads to a contradiction.Which would then complete the proof.

Are my steps upto this point correct?

Comment: Please, don't abuse of bold text.

Comment: Yeah sorry for that.

Comment: So... You are sorry, but you're not gonna fix it?

Comment: I think this should be acceptable?

Comment: why should sup L exist in S? It might exist outside of S. For example if S=(0,1) and B=(0,0.5) then sup L=0 is outside S. Or is there an assumption that S is the universe and nothing exists outside it?

Comment: Since it is an ordered set with lub property. That is any subset of S that is bounded above has a supremum in S.

Comment: True, but for that L should be a subset of S which would only follow if there is the assumption that  S is the universe and nothing exists outside it

Comment: For your example, you have taken S = ( 0 ,1) and B = ( 0 , 0.5 ) which is acceptable but then L = { } which means there is no meaning for sup L. Also from the assumptions, it is clear that B is bounded below which means there exists x in  S such that  x ≤ b for all b in B. In case of your 'B' no such number exists in S.Hence it is not bounded below.